# What do you call the anniversary of moving somewhere?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

My company is soon to celebrate its ten-year anniversary of moving to their new location. We are going to make some posters to announce it, but I can't think of a more succinct, punchy kind of way to say it.

10-Year Anniversary of Moving to 〇〇 ?
10-Year Relocation Anniversary ?

They all sound quite strange and ill-suited for posters. Any suggestions? Thanks much in advance!

Comment: have you checked a thesaurus for anniversary?otherwise I don't think there's a magic word

Comment: The ten-year move-iversary.

Comment: The word _anniversary_  means 'a year since [the event]', so the word _year_ is superfluous; just say _tenth anniversary_.

Comment: perhaps relocation anniversary!

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly, a store will say something like “Celebrating 10 years in this location!”

Answer (score 1):

You've already said it in the the title of your question.

If you don't specify anything, an *anniversary* is thought to be a wedding anniversary. Otherwise, you specify what it's *of* in the sentence:

---

> This is the third anniversary *of my promotion*.
> This is the fifth anniversary *of our store being open*.
>
> This is the *tenth anniversary* ***of us moving here***.

---

Note that [*anniversary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anniversary) normally applies to an annual event:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : the annual recurrence of a date marking a notable event
> // a wedding *anniversary*

However, it doesn't have to. You can specify something other than an annual period of time if you use an adjective before the noun:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> *broadly* : a date that follows such an event by a specified period of time measured in units other than years
> // the 6-month *anniversary* of the accident

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it [Emigration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emigration) day.

> Emigration is the act of leaving a resident country or place of residence with the intent to settle elsewhere.

Technically it is not quite right, but it's a lot punchier than a mere anniversary, and it plainly implies moving is involved.

Comment: Why not "Immigration day" where you celebrate not leaving the old neighborhood, but arriving at the new one.

Comment: @GEdgar That's gotten more politicized, and tied to moving *just* between countries. You could use it, but I think it more likely to cause problems, in the US at least.

Comment: My partner and I are using this answer to name our celebration for the event. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**[Decennial](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/decennial)** (collinsdictionary.com)

> Adjective
>
> 1. lasting for ten years
> 2. occurring every ten years
>
> Noun
>
> 3. a tenth anniversary or its celebration

*The company is celebrating the decennial anniversary of its (shifting to / existence in the current location.)*

*The decennial celebrations of the company's ....*

Comment: "Second Pentennial" ;-)